# Titles in UICollectionView header aren't displaying correctly

Tags: swift, uicollectionview, header

I'm doing Movie app and titles (movies categories) aren't displaying correctly in UICollectionView Header. Instead of "Adventures", it shows "Cartoons" in all categories. What can be wrong in viewForSupplementaryElementOfKind method?

Here's some code:

> ```
> struct MovieCategory {
>
>     let title: String
>     let img: String
>
> }
> ```
>
> class DataSet {
>
> ```
> let categories = [MovieCategory(title: "Cartoons",     img:"coco1.jpg"),
>                   MovieCategory(title: "Adventure", img: "lord.jpg"),
>                   MovieCategory(title: "Drama", img: "titanic.jpg")]
>
> }
> ```

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, viewForSupplementaryElementOfKind kind: String, at indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionReusableView {

            switch kind {
            case UICollectionElementKindSectionHeader:

                let headerView = collectionView.dequeueReusableSupplementaryView(ofKind: kind, withReuseIdentifier: "HeaderCollection", for: indexPath) as! HeaderCollectionReusableView

                headerView.headerLebel.text = myData.categories[indexPath.row].title

                return headerView

            default: assert(false, "Error")

            }

        }
```

Here are some screenshots: [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/oIy4w.jpg,[2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/6XAOH.jpg

Comment: How is set your `cellForRowAtIndexPath`? Are you using sections?

Comment: No I'm not using sections. I have 3 tableView cells (movie categories) and after clicking on each of them it shows movies in the appropriate category in collectionView. 


func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

if let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "toCategories", for: indexPath) as? CustomCellClass {
            
            cell.configureCustomCell(category: myData.categories[indexPath.row])
            return cell
        }
    return UITableViewCell()
    }

Comment: Header will be shown on sections, so that’s normal behavior. Use sections

Comment: Thanks for the tip! I'll try sections.

Answer (score 0):

You are passing `indexPath.row` in every header which is wrong. use `indexPath.section` instead

```
headerView.headerLebel.text = myData.categories[indexPath.section].title
```

Comment: Thank you. Unfortunately, nothing changed :(